# mysqli_fetch_all not working while calling data to other file

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

This file is names as public-function.php

```
function getPublishedPosts() {
// use global $conn object in function
global $conn;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE published=true";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// fetch all posts as an associative array called $posts
$posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
return $posts;
}
```

and while calling data to index.php with command

```
<?php require_once( ROOT_PATH . '/includes/public_functions.php') ?>

<!-- Retrieve all posts from database  -->
<?php $posts = getPublishedPosts(); ?>
```

Its showing the error as:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all() in C:\MAMP\htdocs\complete-blog-php\includes\public_functions.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\complete-blog-php\index.php(10): getPublishedPosts() #1 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\complete-blog-php\includes\public_functions.php on line 12

Comment: The error is about a function called `mysqli_fetch` which isn't in the source code for `getPublishedPosts()` you have here.

Comment: As said in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php#refsect1-mysqli-result.fetch-all-mysqlnd): `mysqli_fetch_all` is "Available only with mysqlnd."

Comment: What should I write so that the programs axecutes as same as it would in mysqlnd

Comment: Something like this
`$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$allData = [];
while ($item = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     $allData[] = $item;
}

print_r($allData);`